# Why does $a += 3 execute faster than $a = $a + 3?

Tags: php, expression

[PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php) states that:

> Adding 3 to the current value of $a can be written '$a += 3'. This
>   means exactly "take the value of $a, add 3 to it, and assign it back
>   into $a". **In addition to being shorter and clearer, this also results
>   in faster execution.**

I used to think that `$a += 3` is merely syntax sugar for `$a = $a + 3` and thus they should be *equal* in all respects.

Why does `$a += 3` result in faster execution compared to `$a = $a + 3`?

Comment: if nothing else, it's slightly less code to parse.

Comment: How do you time it? It would be interesting to know...

Comment: my guess is you can increment $a rather than change $a to a new variable which is just 3 digits larger

Comment: Bench-marked [here](http://codepad.org/gO5B5UlN) if anyone is interested.

Comment: its faster => unoptimized, translator doesn't analysis that one left operand is target operand, It means  if `$a += 3` faster then `$a = $a + 3`, `$a = $a + 3` will be probably faster then  `$a = $a + $a`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment operator advan[t](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3sh-t91)age.

Answer (score 4):

`$a = $a + 3` adds 3 to $a in a temporary memory space, then assigns the result to $a; while `$a += 3` adds 3 directly to $a; so the difference is a few bytes of memory for temporary storage, plus an assignment

Comment: I'm not sure about called 3 times. `$a = $a + 3`: copy $a to temp memory space, add 3 to the value in temp memory space, override value of $a with value from temp memory space; `$a += 3`: add 3 to the value of $a - no need to copy $a to tempspace; no need to write tempspace value to $a

Answer (score 3):

**PHP is an interpreter**, so, in order to have a **good** performance for **good** code, it must restrict itself to **do not** do "valid" complex opimizations (as compilers can do, because they have time for that).
Since the time of asembler, it is better to have `=+` than its equivalent sum, just becouse it uses less resources.
In the case of PHP, it tokenizes `=+` to `T_PLUS_EQUAL`, also best executed by PHP executable, and in the other hand, the sum, well, it is tokenized (and executed) just like a sum.

Following the "dumps" from both `token_get_all()`

```
<?php echo '<pre>';

print_r(array_map(function($t){if(is_array($t)) $t[0]=token_name($t[0]); return $t;},
          token_get_all('<?php $a=$a+3 ?>')));

print_r(array_map(function($t){if(is_array($t)) $t[0]=token_name($t[0]); return $t;},
          token_get_all('<?php $a+=3 ?>')));

// results in:
?>

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => T_OPEN_TAG
            [1] =>  1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => T_VARIABLE
            [1] => $a
            [2] => 1
        )

    [2] => =
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => T_VARIABLE
            [1] => $a
            [2] => 1
        )

    [4] => +
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => T_LNUMBER
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => T_WHITESPACE
            [1] =>  
            [2] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => T_CLOSE_TAG
            [1] => ?>
            [2] => 1
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => T_OPEN_TAG
            [1] =>  1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => T_VARIABLE
            [1] => $a
            [2] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => T_PLUS_EQUAL      /// <= see here!!!!!
            [1] => +=
            [2] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => T_LNUMBER
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => T_WHITESPACE
            [1] =>  
            [2] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => T_CLOSE_TAG
            [1] => ?>
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

`$a = $a + 3` **might** use a temporary variable in the **PHP VM**.
While `$a += 3` **might** execute directly.

**PS**: *I emphasize the might. Very not sure...*

It might be similar to `C++`'s: `++i` vs. `i++` :)